# Field Test Mode

Tags: android

How can I extract the following parameters for the field test:

GPRS attach status, 
GPRS attach type, 
PTMSI, 
MAC mode, and
RAU Timer

From where can I extract these details? I did a lot of search in Framework component and i couldn't find any matching functions.